# Blender noise texture scaled in z axis by default?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Can someone confirm if this is normal behavior? It appears the noise texture by default is "squeezed" in the z axis. Below I am showing it as default and with scale up by 0.5 applied to lengthen in the z axis.

Default:
[image: Default]

Corrected?:
[image: Scaled]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Texture coordinates matters

**No**, by default the noise texture is **isotropic**. Here's a picture of it covering the default cube:

[image]

You are probably experiencing that "strange" behaviour becaues you are feeding the vector socket of the texture with a non-uniform vector fields.

As said in the manual, [Generated texture](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html):

> ... [automatically-generate] coordinates from the vertex positions of the mesh without deformation, keeping them sticking to the surface under animation. Range from 0.0 to 1. 0 over the bounding box of the undeformed mesh.

This means that if your object has a non-uniform bounding box (even a loose vertice counts), you'll get different density of the vector field in the 3d space to be able to guarantee the same range. A tall object will show a stretched texture upon the z-axis, while in a short (as in your case) will look squeezed.

See in this image sequance how altering the x-size of the object by modifying its mesh (e.g. moving some vertices) leads to a stretch of the texture on that axis.

[image]

If you want to keep the texture's size indipendent from the object's bounding box you should use **Object Texture coordinates**, maybe targeting an Empty if you want to keep the size consistent across multiple object (Object's Texture coordinates is object's transformations dipendent).

Comment: Carlo, thanks for the detailed explanation! I used the sculpt brush to modify the plane, this must have caused the issue, which I would not have suspected.. I also tried applying transformation and it did not help. Btw the cube was added to the mesh in edit mode after I noticed the issue.